# Как при выборке с БД исключить попадание в коллекцию элемента с определенным id?

Tags: laravel, коллекции

На сайте интернет-магазина, на странице карточки товара внизу выводятся 4 позиции товаров из этой же категории. Они выбираются случайным образом. Иногда, в коллекцию попадает товар, в карточке, которого показывается эта выборка. Как не допустить его попадания в коллекцию ?

```
public function single(Request $request, $id)
{
  // получение 4-х случайных товаров из данной категории

  $product = Product::find($id);
  // категория товара
  $category = $product->category_id;
  // все товары из данной категории
  $sort_by_category = Product::where('category_id', '=', $category)->get();
  // 4 случайные позиции
  $related_products = $sort_by_category->random(4);

  return view ('pages.single', [
    'product' => $product,
    'related_products' => $related_products
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дополнительным условием `where('id', '<>', $product->id)` вы можете исключить уже выбранный продукт. А также для случайной выборки используйте метод `inRandomOrder()`

```php
public function single(Request $request, $id)
{
  $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

  $related_products = Product::inRandomOrder()
    ->where('category_id', '=', $product->category_id)
    ->where('id', '<>', $product->id)
    ->take(4)
    ->get();

    return view ('pages.single', compact('product', 'related_products'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Псевдокод:

```
$random_products = [];
while (len($random_products) < 4){
    $random_item = $sort_by_category->random(1);
    if (($random_item != $product) AND ($random_item not in $random_products)) {
        $random_products = $random_products + $random_item 
    }
```

Описание:
наполняем массив `$random_products` случайными товарами по одному до тех пор, пока в нем не станет 4 товара. Перед добавлением товара делается проверка

- случайный товар не такой же, чья карточка показывается,
- случайный товар еще не добавлен в список.